# Automatically finding and merging adjacent lines in large data set using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge, contour, qgis-modeler

I need to merge adjacent lines in QGIS 3.8, but am having trouble coming up with a way to identify and then merge them in a large data set. (3.8 is as far as my Mac can support)

I tried to convert my lines to polygons and use the "Join multiple lines" plugin. With both of these it seems like I'll need to select everything manually (*not a feasible option*) first or else it gets messy.

Ex. I want to locate lines like on the right here with touching endpoints, and merge them into one like on the left.

[image]

Comment: Convert your line ends into points https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306190/generate-start-and-end-points-in-qgis-for-linestrings, buffer ends with dissolve, convert multipart to single https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74413/how-to-convert-result-of-dissolved-buffer-into-individual-polygons (last answer) then count the points in the buffer http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/qgis/points-in-polygon/ - remove any with count != 2 can't be merged as they are either dangles or true intersections. Iterate the remaining polygons, select intersecting lines then dissolve them.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and just used (1) Dissolve and (2) Multipart to Single Part to resolve the merges. Ended up being a lot simpler than some of the other proposed solutions, but perhaps it doesn't work on all datasets? See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376050/merging-touching-lines-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to union and merge touching lines in a self join SQL, then run a multipart to singlepart geometry with the QGIS geometry tools.

Make a virtual layer - where mylines is your layername - like

```
select st_linemerge(st_union(m1.geometry)) as geometry
from mylines m1
inner join mylines m2 on st_touches(m1.geometry, m2.geometry)
```

Then on the virtual layer run Vector > Geometry tools > Multipart to Singleparts

Anyone knows how to include the Multipart to Singleparts in SQL - I am happy to hear ..

Comment: You can use recursive functions to try and emulate `ST_Dump()` (the equivalent function in PostGIS). See examples in these answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341570/98784 and [Chainage points using virtual layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333244/qgis-geometry-generator-chainage-nodes-and-labels-along-line/333271#333271)

Comment: Here is an example query: `WITH RECURSIVE rng(x) AS( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT (x+1) FROM rng LIMIT ( SELECT cast(st_numgeometries(geometry) AS int) FROM line_collected)), line_collected AS (SELECT st_linemerge(st_union(m1.geometry)) as geometry, m1.id FROM mylines m1 INNER JOIN mylines m2 ON st_touches(m1.geometry, m2.geometry)) SELECT geometry_n(lc.geometry, rng.x) AS geometry, rng.x AS part_num FROM rng, line_collected lc;`